# Mapped component with dedicated state in React loses state on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having this issue where I have an array and a component like this:

```
const Animal = ({ data }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(data);
  const updateName = (event) =>
    setState((old) => ({ name: event.target.value, ...old }));
  console.log({ state }, state.name);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{state.animal}</h3>
      <h3>{state.name}</h3>
      <input onChange={updateName} />
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    { animal: "cat", name: "muji", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0 },
    { animal: "cat", name: "mine", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1 },
    { animal: "dog", name: "fido", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1 },
    { animal: "dog", name: "fido2", date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1 },
    { animal: "dog", name: "fido3", date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0 },
    { animal: "hamster", name: "gerry", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0 },
    { animal: "t-rex", name: "dino", date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0 },
    { animal: "sheep", name: "s", date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0 }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item, idx) => {
        return <Animal data={item} key={idx} />;
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

After updating the name of the animal the state suddenly loses all the properties and leaves only the name.

Here's a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-river-93674?file=/src/App.js:86-411)

Thanks!

Edit:

I have also tried setting the data in a state like this but nothing changed:

```js
useState([...])
```

Comment: How are you updating the state? There is nothing changing in the UI.

Comment: The code in your sandbox is not the same as the code in your question...

Comment: I know and that's the problem that I'm having. In the Animal component there's a function called `updateName` if you haven't noticed.  That's where I'm trying to update it. Thanks!

Comment: @TJ I have updated it. I was experimenting to try to see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` property is being overridden by old value because order of propeties is incorrect in `setState`.

Instead of

```js
setState((old) => ({  name: event.target.value,...old,  }))
```

It should be

```js
setState((old) => ({  ...old, name: event.target.value, }))
```

and your input element was missing `value` attribute

```js
const Animal = ({ data }) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({...data});

   const updateName = (event) =>{
    setState((old) => ({  ...old, name: event.target.value, }))
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{state.animal}</h3>
      <h3>{state.name}</h3>
      <input value={state.name} onChange={updateName} />
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have to wait for 5 minutes so that it lets me :)